# Regex to match string with the latest date

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which finds all occurrences of a text pattern.

Example of text to match with regex (the number of occurrences can vary, from 1 up to 7.  In this example there are two.

31.05.18 SB RS BW
18.05.18 SB RS BW

The regex finds all occurrences of the string.

I need the regex to find the string with the latest date only.  (eg find the string with the date (31.05.18 SB RS BW)

Important to note that the date will change each time the script is run, so will be unable to hard code the date into the regex.

```
var re = new RegExp("\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2,4}\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})\\s([A-Z]{2,5})");
```

If anyone can provide assistance so that the regex matches the pattern with the latest date only, that would be most appreciated - thank you

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for this, and you should be checking the date values in your app/database layer.  Regex _might_ be appropriate for _extracting_ that date string from each line, but not for checking the value.

Comment: Agree with Tim. However, we can only suggest alternatives if you tell us what's your language or tool.

Comment: Regexes are for *pattern matching* and nothing else. They're not for mathematical operations (the greater of these values). You're trying to use the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I am using the regular expression in Adobe pdf javascript, it will help find the words and then place a text form field around the words.  I need the script to place the form fields on the latest date only